# Git: How to recover from changed history?

Tags: git, git-merge

A highly recommended practice is not to change history for commits pushed elsewhere that others will have pulled. Nonetheless, people who don't understand this will inevitably do it anyway. From the perspective of the "other users", not the person who changed history themselves, what's the best way to recover from this?

Here's an example to make it specific.

**Ryan creates a few commits and pushes:**

```
ryan $ git init
ryan $ echo "initial stuff" > file.txt
ryan $ git add file.txt
ryan $ git commit -m "Initial commit" 
ryan $ echo "more stuff" >> file.txt
ryan $ git add file.txt
ryan $ git commit -m "More stuff"
ryan $ git remote add origin [some url]
ryan $ git push origin
```

**Joe clones the github repo**

```
joe $ git clone [some url]
```

At this point, all is well, then ...

**Ryan changes the last commit:**

```
ryan $ vi file.txt
ryan $ git add file.txt
ryan $ git commit --amend -m "More stuff"
ryan $ git push origin
       [Fails]
ryan $ git push -f origin master
```

Note that Ryan did a forced push after it failed otherwise. This would be fine if he was the only one pulling from origin, but in this case, he's just screwed up Joe.

**Joe tries to pull:**

```
joe $ git pull origin
      [Conflict!]
```

Now this is a very simple example but it's likely that Joe isn't familiar with `file.txt` and is going to find it difficult to merge the change.

Again, I understand that the root of the problem is that Ryan did something bad. But nonetheless, I'm looking for ways that Joe and his teammates can recover from it without having to do a merge commit.

I do know one trick which is to delete your local copy of the remote branch then re-check it out from origin. But of course this only works if you have no changes. It's likely that Joe's made some new changes of his own which he wants to commit.

Thoughts?

Comment: What about rejecting forced pushes, at least for branches like master?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld not a bad idea, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to save away the commit on origin before it was rewritten (or you can find it afterwards but before is easier)

```
git branch save_point origin/master (before fetch)
```

Then do the fetch, this changes nothing

```
git fetch
```

Now all commits in Joe's repository not already on master needs to be rewritten/rebased onto the rewritten commit from origin

```
git rebase --onto origin/master save_point master
```

If the changes on the different branches aren't related this should work just fine.

You can read about this in the [manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) but it's not trivial to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the commit graph.  Here's Ryan's original:

```
A - B
```

`A` is the "initial commit" and `B` is the first "more stuff".

Joe gets this and starts working.  Let's say he adds a commit `C`, too, just so we have more stuff in Joe's graph:

```
A - B - C
```

Meanwhile Ryan goes and does the amend and force-push.  This creates:

```
A - B
  \
    B'
```

where `B'` is the "amended" commit.

If Joe now does a fetch (or pull, which of course does a fetch), here's what he gets:

```
A - B - C       <-- HEAD=master
  \
    B'          <-- origin/master
```

Basically, he still has the original `B`.

To recover, Joe needs to rebase his commits (in this case, just `C`) onto the new `origin/master` commit, `B'`.

If Joe uses `git pull --rebase`, git does something clever: it can tell that commit `B` *used to be* the tip commit of `origin/master`, and thus, that only commit `C` needs to be rebased.

If Joe uses `git fetch` (or `git pull` without `--rebase`), git will update `origin/master` to point to `B'` and make it harder to figure out that `B'` corresponds to `B`.  (It's easy to see in these simplified, hand-drawn graphs, but much harder to see in real git commit DAGs after-the-fact.)  However, if Joe is able to identify "his" vs "theirs" in spite of Ryan's cruel trick :-) , he can do the same rebase.

(I find a simple `rebase -i` is often sufficient, since I can usually tell "my" commits from "theirs" and delete the appropriate `pick` lines.)

(Edit: see [Andreas Wederbrand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19597876/1256452) for what `pull --rebase` does internally: it's using `rebase --onto upstream start_after branch`.  It gets *`upstream`* and *`branch`* in the usual way for any pull, and it knows the *`start_after`* SHA-1 from what was in `origin/branch` before the `pull --rebase` step.)